# In Unity, GetDirectories() does not work on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, resources, getfiles, getdirectories

I've been trying to retrieve directories within Resources folder (Assets -> Resources -> DiscoveryPage -> Bloggers -> *various folders I want to get*), and it only works on Unity Editor on run time, but not on my Android device.

Here's what I have:

```
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
        //discoveryDir = new DirectoryInfo(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/DiscoveryPage/Bloggers");
        //discoveryDir = new DirectoryInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Resources/DiscoveryPage/Bloggers");
        discoveryDir = new DirectoryInfo("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets" + "/Resources/DiscoveryPage/Bloggers");

        MainUI.ShowDebug("Running on Android. @" + discoveryDir.Name);
} else {
        discoveryDir = new DirectoryInfo(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/DiscoveryPage/Bloggers");
}

    bloggerDirs = discoveryDir.GetDirectories();
    if (bloggerDirs == null)
        MainUI.ShowDebug("bloggerDirs is null");
    else
        MainUI.ShowDebug("bloggerDirs is NOT null");
```

The line:

```
MainUI.ShowDebug("Running on Android. @" + discoveryDir.Name);
```

did show up with proper information (I was able to reach Bloggers folder and get the discoveryDir.Name, but

```
if (bloggerDirs == null)
 MainUI.ShowDebug("bloggerDirs is null");
else
 MainUI.ShowDebug("bloggerDirs is NOT null");
```

bloggerDirs doesn't return anything (not even null). Neither debug line was printed out.

Seems like discoveryDir.GetDirectories(); does not work on Android.

Anyone knows the problem and how to get those directories on Android run time?